# Swift TableView More Loading Button

Tags: swift, realm

I searched for a lot of website/pages , mostly is about objective-c.

I have (unlimited)datas somethings like FavoriteViewController which store the what you like to display on a table. But i will only display 20 records firstly, and when the user clicks the last row (Load More Button) then table will row the next 20 records.

I am using RealM and below is my code

```
FavouriteViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return favouriteList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "main", for: indexPath) as! favouriteTableViewCell
  ...
  return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let maxCell : Int = 20
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "main", for: indexPath) as! favouriteTableViewCell
    cell.number = indexPath.row
    if cell.number > maxCell {
        let view = UIView()
        let moreButton = UIButton()
        moreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreButtonClick(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = view
        view.addSubview(moreButton)
    }
 tableView.reloadData()
}

@objc func moreButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
    print("load more")
}
```

My question is how can I display the 20 records firstly and how can I click the moreButton and display another more 20 records.

Comment: could you clarify what the question is?

Comment: Sorry for that and I updated my questions.

Comment: Do you have all the records beforehand or you fetch it from API every time?

Comment: ya. I do.. I can fetch it everytime

Comment: Why are you displaying only 20 records a a time? It would probably be a better experience for the user if they could just scroll through the list. If you really only want to display 20 records at a time, you just need to keep track of the last index that's being displayed. So initally you display indexes 0-19. Then when the click Load More, load in 20-39 and display them. etc. The question is unclear though - maybe if you can clarify it we can provide an answer.

Comment: If `favouriteList` is fully populated at the start, then you can just keep a count of how many records you wish to display and return that number from `numberOfRowsInSection`, so `moreButtonClick` could be `count = min(count + 20, favouriteList.count)` and a call to `tableView.reloadData`. Ditch `willDisplayCell`.

Comment: to Jay: exactly like what you said.. how can i do that ? to Chris Shaw i have put return 20 at numberOfRowsInSection and moreButtonClick count = min(count + 20, favouriteList.count) and i still can’t work it

Comment: @FREECSSNGOI Use `return count` from `numberOfRowsInSection`, make everything else a standard datasource implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, the poster wants to load a certain number of items from Realm and display them in a tableView. Then when the user clicks a Next button, it will load the next set of items. This is sometimes called pagination.

Starting with a Realm Object

```
class ItemClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var item_name = ""
    @objc dynamic var item_index = ""
}
```

and then a class results object which we'll use as our datasource along with a integer var to keep track of what the first item is in the set of data being displayed

```
var itemResults: Results<ItemClass>!
var startingIndex = 0
```

then we'll create 20 test items in realm with the name being Item X and the index being an integer index of the item.

```
var itemArray = [ItemClass]()

for i in 0..<20 {
    let item = ItemClass()
    let num = "Item \(i)"
    item.item_number = num
    item.index = i
    try realm.write {
       realm.add(item)
    }
}
```

When the app first starts, we'll load in 5 items from Realm and populate our tableView dataSource. These items will be the items at index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

```
func loadItems() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.itemResults = realm.objects(ItemClass.self).filter("index >= 0 AND index <=4").sorted(byKeyPath: "index")
    //the next time data is loaded, we'll start with item at index of 5
    self.startingIndex = 5 
}
```

then, later on we have a button that the user clicks to load in 5 more and replace the ones being shown. The first time the button is clicked it will load in items at index 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. The the next button click will load 10, 11, 12, 13, 14. Etc etc.

```
func handleTestButton2Action() {
    let endingIndex = self.startingIndex + 4
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.itemResults = realm.objects(ItemClass.self).filter("index >= %i AND index <= %i", self.startingIndex, endingIndex).sorted(byKeyPath: "index")
    self.startingIndex = endingIndex + 1
    self.itemTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
class FavouriteViewController: UIViewController,
UITableViewDataSource,
UITableViewDelegate,
CustomFooterDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let resultsStep = 20
var maxResults : Int = 20
var allItems = Result<FavoriteItem>!
var favouriteList: Result<FavoriteItem>!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    loadResults()
}

func loadResults() {
    allItems = realm.objects(FavoriteItem.self)
    limitShownItems()
}

func limitShownItems() {
    favouriteList = allItems.prefix(maxResults)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return favouriteList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "main", for: indexPath) as! favouriteTableViewCell

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomFooter") as! CustomFooter
    view.delegate = self

    return view
}


//MARK: - CustomFooterDelegate
func didTapAddMoreResults(view: CustomFooter) {
    maxResults = maxResults + resultsStep
    limitShownItems()
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

}

I did not made a test or something, hope it works :D